# Reference request: Models of set theory and relativization

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I am self-studying set theory and have been using Jech's text. When reading chapter 12, things are ok until I get to the section "Models of Set Theory and Relativization."

I do not understand a single word written in this section. What is a "relativized formula" for a class M and binary relation E? Jech writes a formula with free variables and then says "the variables are implicitly assumed to range over M." But what does this mean if it is just an abstract formula?

Since I don't even know where to begin with asking a question on here (since I do not understand any of it at all) I have therefore been searching online for another reference that explains the material in this section. Can somebody recommend another reference for this material?

Comment: I have never posted a 'reference request' before - I hope this is the right way to post it. Thank you.

Comment: In what way is Definition 12.6 (p.161) of Jech's _Set Theory_ (Third Millennium ed.) unclear?

Comment: I understand the formal construction of how he writes down the relativised formula. But then he says that we can instead write (M,E) ⊨  ϕ(x1, . . . , xn) in its place. What does this mean? And then given a formula ϕ in set theory we write ⌜φ⌝ to distinguish it. What is ⌜φ⌝? e.g. if  ϕ is x ∈ y what then is  ⌜φ⌝?

Comment: He seems to be talking about a formula ϕ(x1, . . . , xn) in the language of set theory, and then speaks as though the xi are elements of M. I feel like I don't even understand enough to ask a specific question...

Comment: Some of the results from the google search for [stackexchange "set theory" models "reference request"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange+%22set+theory%22+models+%22reference+request%22) should be helpful, such as the math stackexchange questions [What are the prerequisites to Jech's Set theory text?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389212/what-are-the-prerequisites-to-jechs-set-theory-text) and [Jech's Set Theory logic prerequisites](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182712/jechs-set-theory-logic-prerequisites).

Comment: Thank you for your post. I do know the basic facts of mathematical logic (completeness theorem etc) but it seems most people do not recommend Jech as a first encounter with set theory. The book has been ok (by no means easy) so far. Perhaps I need a different book.

Comment: If $\phi$ is $x\in y$ then the relativization of $\phi$ to $M$ is $x\in y$. Relativizations of formulas only differ from the original formula when it has quantifiers. Quantifiers then "range over" the object that the formula has been relativized to